# How to merge this eventproc code with checkdata code?

Tags: events, vba, excel

I recently was helped in creating some checkdata code as shown here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    CheckData Me.Range("C3:V65")
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    CheckData Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:V65"))
End Sub
Sub CheckData(rng As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        icolor = 0
        Select Case cell
            Case "": icolor = 2
            Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3
            Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 6
            Case Is > Date + 60: icolor = 2
        End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```

I used this on a workbook that essentially only had one macro that needed to be run for the range specified. However, I have this code below set up from before in another workbook that I need to modify so that the checkdata function works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        EventProc1 Target
        EventProc2 Target

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub EventProc1(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim icolor As Integer
        Dim cell As Range

        If Intersect(Target, Range("L2:L55")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        For Each cell In Target
            icolor = 0
            Select Case cell
                Case "": icolor = 2

                Case Is <= Date + 120: icolor = 3 
                Case Is <= Date + 180: icolor = 6 
                Case Is > Date + 180: icolor = 2

            End Select
            If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
        Next cell
    End Sub

    Private Sub EventProc2(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim icolor As Integer
        Dim cell As Range

        If Intersect(Target, Range("O2:O55")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        For Each cell In Target
            icolor = 0
            Select Case cell
                Case "": icolor = 2

                Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3 
                Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 45
                Case Is <= Date + 90: icolor = 6 
                Case Is > Date + 90: icolor = 2 

            End Select
            If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

I suspect that I can merge the two Worksheet_Change events like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        CheckData Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:V65"))

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        EventProc1 Target
        EventProc2 Target

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

But from here, I don't know how to convert the Sub EventProc1/2 into the new CheckData format. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the "new" CheckData format? Do you understand what the code is doing? You seem to be on the right track - what is not working as you are expecting it? You have to be a little bit more specific with your question...

Answer (score 0):

As you say there is nothing wrong with your codes but I've made a few mods to get them in the same format as the `checkdata` and I like these better as the ranges you force the colors on are not hard coded:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)            
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    CheckData Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C3:V65"))

    EventProc1 Intersect(Target, Me.Range("L2:L55"))
    EventProc2 Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O2:O55"))

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**EventProc1:**

```
Sub EventProc1 (rng As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        icolor = 0
            Select Case cell
                Case "": icolor = 2                    
                Case Is <= Date + 120: icolor = 3 
                Case Is <= Date + 180: icolor = 6 
                Case Is > Date + 180: icolor = 2           
            End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```

**EventProc2:**

```
Sub EventProc2 (rng As Range)
    Dim icolor As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        icolor = 0
            Select Case cell
                Case "": icolor = 2                    
                Case Is <= Date + 30: icolor = 3 
                Case Is <= Date + 60: icolor = 45
                Case Is <= Date + 90: icolor = 6 
                Case Is > Date + 90: icolor = 2            
            End Select
        If icolor <> 0 Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = icolor
    Next cell
End Sub
```